# Understanding MVC in a QAbstractTableModel

Tags: model-view-controller, pyqt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have some data which are represented by a class of my own ; to fix the ideas I give an example.

```python
class MyOwnModel():
  def __init__(self, name="", number=0):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
```

I then have a list of such instances, that I want to represent in a `QTableView`.

```python
li = [MyOwnModel("a", 1), MyOwnModel("b", 2)]
```

Then I see two strategies to make a `QTableView` from that :

1. change `MyOwnModel` so that it subclasses `QAbstractTableModel`
2. build a new `QAbstractTableModel` which mimics `MyOwnModel` in a way that its attributes are for instance two `QString` and connect the `dataChanged` signal to a function which updates the instance of `MyOwnModel`

I am not completely satisfied with any of these, but I have no other idea for the moment.

Which one is the most suitable to my problem ? (I have a more complex class in practice but I would like to use the same framework)

Comment: The `MyOwnModel` class clearly isn't any kind of model. It's just a simple namespace that holds one item of data. So neither of your strategies can possibly work. An abstract model wraps the underlying data (which in your case is just a list), and provides a standard interface for accessing the items. See the [Model Subclassing Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) in the Qt Docs. Or just use a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment, your model is your list of object. You should subclass `QAbstractTableModel` to use this list.

Here's my code snippet for this:

```python
import sys
import signal
import PyQt4.QtCore as PCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as PGui

class OneRow(PCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.column0="text in column 0"
        self.column1="text in column 1"

class TableModel(PCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TableModel,self).__init__()
        self.myList=[]

    def addRow(self,rowObject):
        row=len(self.myList)
        self.beginInsertRows(PCore.QModelIndex(),row,row)
        self.myList.append(rowObject)
        self.endInsertRows()

    #number of row
    def rowCount(self,QModelIndex):
        return len(self.myList)

    #number of columns
    def columnCount(self,QModelIndex):
        return 2

    #Define what do you print in the cells
    def data(self,index,role):
        row=index.row()
        col=index.column()
        if role==PCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if col==0:
                return str( self.myList[row].column0)
            if col==1:
                return str( self.myList[row].column1)

    #Rename the columns
    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role):
        if role==PCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation==PCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section==0:
                    return str("Column 1")
                elif section==1:
                    return str("Column 2")

if __name__=='__main__':
    PGui.QApplication.setStyle("plastique")
    app=PGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    #Model
    model=TableModel()
    model.addRow(OneRow())
    model.addRow(OneRow())

    #View
    win=PGui.QTableView()
    win.setModel(model)

    #to be able to close wth ctrl+c
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    #to avoid warning when closing
    win.setAttribute(PCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Each element of `myList` is a row in the table.

Comment: Your solution with addRow is very nice ! Thanks !

Comment: Always ensure models have a parent - that will eliminate the warnings on exit, because things will then get deleted in the right order.