# PySide/PyQt QAbstractItemModel Questions

Tags: pyqt, pyside, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

Ive been researching this all day, and despite looking at things like:

http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/using_qtreeview_with_qabstractitemmodel

http://trevorius.com/scrapbook/uncategorized/pyqt-custom-abstractitemmodel/

http://blog.rburchell.com/2010/02/pyside-tutorial-model-view-programming_22.html

I am entirely stumped. I either can't even get the example working, or when i can, I am unable to bend it to do what I want.

Basically I want to build a model to which i can input a list of dicts. The len() of my list would be my rows, and then len() of any of their keys would be my column count.

I am entirely new to these item models (I usually use TableWidget, ListWidget, etc and their built in implementations), and I'm not understanding how to properly set data, add rows with the beginInsertRows/endInsertRows, and even when i accidnetally get that working, trying to figure out when and how to add my columns as well always causes all sorts of bad.

I was wondering if anyone had any examples I can draw from - something simple with the basis of what I'm missing. for instance:
given

```
myList = [
{'name': 'John Smith', 'occupation': 'Police', 'Gender': 'Male'},
{'name': 'Jane Smith', 'occupation': 'CEO', 'Gender': 'Female'},
{'name': 'Ranoutta Ideas', 'occupation': 'Not Creativity', 'Gender': 'Male'},
]
```

I would want to insert that into my model and get 3 rows, each with 3 columns, and maybe the key names as headers.

Is anyone able to point me on a good path?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I tried an example from the comments:

import sys
    import signal
    import PyQt4.QtCore as PCore
    import PyQt4.QtGui as PGui

```
class OneRow(PCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
    self.column0="text in column 0"
    self.column1="text in column 1"

class TableModel(PCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
    super(TableModel,self).__init__()
    self.myList=[]

    def addRow(self,rowObject):
    row=len(self.myList)
    self.beginInsertRows(PCore.QModelIndex(),row,row)
    self.myList.append(rowObject)
    self.endInsertRows()

    #number of row
    def rowCount(self,QModelIndex):
    return len(self.myList)

    #number of columns
    def columnCount(self,QModelIndex):
    return 2

    #Define what do you print in the cells
    def data(self,index,role):
    row=index.row()
    col=index.column()
    if role==PCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if col==0:
            return str( self.myList[row].column0)
        if col==1:
            return str( self.myList[row].column1)

    #Rename the columns
    def headerData(self,section,orientation,role):
    if role==PCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation==PCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if section==0:
                return str("Column 1")
            elif section==1:
                return str("Column 2")

if __name__=='__main__':
    PGui.QApplication.setStyle("plastique")
    app=PGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    #Model
    model=TableModel()
    model.addRow(OneRow())
    model.addRow(OneRow())

    #View
    win=PGui.QTableView()
    win.setModel(model)

    #to be able to close wth ctrl+c
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    #to avoid warning when closing
    win.setAttribute(PCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However i end up with a one of errors:

TypeError: invalid result type from TableModel.headerData()
TypeError: invalid result type from TableModel.data()

and no text shows in the cells. I also dont get header labels.
If i change it from returning strings to return QVariant's - i get the text in the cells/headers, but still get tons of those error prints

EDIT:
If i make it fall back to return an empty QVariant, no more error prints - totally missed that. Im going to play with this set up and see if i can get it working as i need, and if so, ill post it here as an answer in case others come accross my struggles

Comment: Couldn't you have only one dictionary like `{'name': ['John','Jane'], 'Gender': ['Male','Female']}` ? For the model you can look at `QStandardItemModel`, or [this example of QAbtractTableModel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30776237/4720935)

Comment: @tmoreau Yeah i COULD, i just didnt start that route because it would add a large step - the data i get from the call i want to fill the table with is a list of dicts. I could format them, but if I dont need to its even better.

I tried the example you posted, and still couldnt get anything to happen - edits are above

Comment: Btw. the example runs smoothly for me.